# How to set default application per image type?

Tags: 22.04, default-programs

In Ubuntu settings - default applications. All images are assigned to one application.

Is there a way to assign only .svg to Inkscape please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click an .svg file in Files (nautilus). Select "Properties" and then use the "Open with" tab to set the default application for files of type "SVG image". Set a different default application for graphics files with a different extension.

Comment: Right click svg - open with other application - choose inkscape - click select (only other option is cancel). Close Inkscape. Double click the file again. Opens in image viewer, not inkscape :(

Comment: Ohh, you mean right click and open properties. That works, thanks!